# Creating a Junction Point on a remote Server (Networkdrive)

Tags: powershell, junction

I'm trying to create Junction Points in PowerShell. This command on my local Drive works very well:

```
$Local = New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path C:\install\junction -value C:\cygwin64
```

This is the same command but for a Network Drive (Remote Server)

```
$Netwo = New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path I:\TRANSFER\Junction -value I:\somewhere
```

This command does not throw an error, so the junction point got successfully created

I also tried to do it with UNC-path `\\server\share\somewhere` and even with the Local Path from the server like `D:\Data\somewhere` but it still doesn't let me access the Junction I created on the Remote Server.

Does anybody know why?

This is the error screenshot, unfortunately in german, but it basically says "the path is not available"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sysinternals junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) util mentions:

> Note: that Windows does not support junctions to directories on remote shares.

I can't find any MS KB article that confirms this, but I'm inclined to believe Mark Russinovich on this as he really knows his stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question has already been asked and answered to the OP's satisfaction. But I'm wondering if there is another interpretation of the question that was missed. Specifically, I don't think he was asking to make a junction whose target is a remote share.

Instead, I think he was trying to create a normal local junction on a remote server which is entirely doable with the use of typical powershell remoting type commands like this:

```
# using cmd's mklink
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server -ScriptBlock { & cmd.exe /c mklink /j c:\junction c:\real }

# or if you want to keep it 100% powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server -ScriptBlock { New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path c:\junction -Value c:\real }
```

To the client who has `I:` mapped to a `\\Server\c$` share, this would be the equivalent of creating an `I:\junction` pointing to `I:\real`.